# Difficult question on integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

> we denote by $\overline{u}$ a positif fuction "radially symmetric
>   about the origin" that realize $$\inf\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} (|\nabla
>  u|^2+\lambda u^2) dx, u\in H^1_0({\mathbb{R}^N}), \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}
>  |u|^p=1\},$$ Then consider the function $w_{\rho}\in
>  H^1_0(B_{\rho}(0))$ defined by $$w_{\rho}(x)=c_{\rho}\xi_{\rho}(x)
>  \overline{u}(x)$$ where $\xi_{\rho}(x):\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow [0,1]$
>   is a $C^{\infty}-$function defined by
>   $$\xi_{\rho}(x)=\tilde{\xi}(\frac{|x|}{\rho})$$ with $\tilde{\xi}:
>  \mathbb{R}^+\cup\{0\}\rightarrow [0,1]$ being a decreasing
>   $C^{\infty}-$function such that $$\tilde{\xi}(t)=\begin{cases}
>  1,~t\leq\frac12,\\0, t\geq 1\end{cases}$$ $c_{\rho}=|\xi_{\rho}
>  \overline{u}|_{L^p(B_{\rho})}$

**My question is How to prove that 
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|(\overline{u}-w_{\rho})(x)|^p dx\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus {B_{\rho/2}(0)}}|\overline{u(x)}|^p dx$**

I try to prove it but i only proved that

- $c_{\rho}=|\overline{u}|_{L^p(B_{\rho/2})}$ and
- $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |(\overline{u}-w_{\rho})(x)|^p=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus B_{\rho}}|\overline{u}|^p dx+\int_{B_{\frac{\rho}{2}}} |1-|\overline{u}|_{L^p(B_{\rho/2})}|^p |\overline{u}|^p dx$

Thank you

Comment: "positif question" should be "positive function"? Also, some absolute value character $|$ is missing in the first formula of the part where you put your question?

Comment: of course positif function